# How to get a value from specificed key

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js, lodash

```
var keys = ['name','age','gender'];

var input = {"document":
             {"people":[
                {"name":["Harry Potter"],"age":["18"],"gender":["Male"]},
                {"name":["hermione granger"],"age":["18"],"gender":["Female"]},
             ]}
            }
```

How to get values from specific key. Example `{Harry Potter, 18, Male}`?

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON, these are regular javascript arrays/objects. But `input.document.people[0].name` would give you `"Harry Potter"`.

Comment: using lo-dash, _.pluck(input.document.people, 'name')

Answer (score 1):

You could use **[pick](http://underscorejs.org/#pick)** to extract the properties that you're interested in:

```
var people = _.map(input.document.people, function(person){
    return _.flatten( _.values(_.pick(person, keys)));
});
```

```js
angular.module('MyModule', [])

.controller('MyController', function($scope) {

  var keys = ['name','age','gender'];

  var input = {"document":
             {"people":[
                {"name":["Harry Potter"],"age":["18"],"gender":["Male"]},
                {"name":["hermione granger"],"age":["18"],"gender":["Female"]}
             ]}
            };
               
  var people = _.map(input.document.people, function(person){
    return _.flatten( _.values(_.pick(person, keys)));
  });
  
  $scope.people = people;
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='MyModule' ng-controller='MyController'>
  <p ng-repeat='person in people'>{{person | json}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Iterate through **input.document.people** and use keys from keys array as

```
for(x in input.document.people){
  for(y in keys){
     console.log(input.document.people[x][keys[y]])
  }
}
```

Please [**refer to fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mazzu/8tk6gmas/) for same

Comment: Please suggest what to use then?

Comment: `for` and `forEach` are there to interate arrays, `for...in` is for objects.

Comment: Is there any specific reason not to use for objects or arrays?

Comment: [Yes.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea)